# Is there a function for checking multiple buttons pressed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, button, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone tell me if there is a simple way to check if a button is clicked, but insted of making the individual check (button1_click event and so on for the others), a function that would be like: "If any button clicked..." here is my code to try to understand what I want:

```
        {
            bCicle();
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bCicle();
        }

        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bCicle();
        }
```

As you can see, I have 3 of the same function for different buttons, but in the entire code, I need to repeat this for 64 buttons...so I want to know if there is a simple way of doing this insted of writing the same thing 64 times.

thanks for your attention.

Comment: Use the same Button.Click handler for all your Buttons. Maybe name the handler, e.g., `buttons_Click`.

Comment: I am using visual studio, how do I use the same handler for them all?

Comment: 1) Remove all the Click handlers you have, except one. 2) Rename it `buttons_Click` (`CTRL+.` to confirm), 3) Open up the Form's Designer (`F7`) 4) Select all the Buttons that need to share this handler 5) In the Properties Panel, switch to the Event View, open the ComboBox selector of the `Click` event and pick `buttons_Click` as the handler for all the selected Buttons.

Comment: ohh, now it makes sense! Wow, thanks so much!